# How to apply exact force to a parking brake peddle

Tags: parking-brake

My 2008 Mazda CX-9 service manual includes the following for parking brake inspection:

- Inspect the parking brake stoke when depressed at 180 N { 18.4 kgf, 40.5 lbf }
- Parking brake pedal stoke when depressed at 180 N { 18.4 kgf, 40.5 lbf }
- 1-3 notches

So seems they want to make sure 180 N of force results in the pedal only depressing a few notches.

How does one go about applying specifically 180 N of push force? Some type of trick to this or is a special tool needed for this?

Comment: There are many ways to go about this, but it seriously doesn't seem worth the effort of getting a properly calibrated force gauge. You could jank it up with a bathroom scale if you wanted, but just consider what leg pressing 40lbs would feel like, then repeat it. Unlike a torque spec, this really isn't as important. Parking brake adjustment is typically done by feel.

Comment: Your parking brake is fine, leave it alone.

Comment: Cheers Hari, scales, interesting. cory actually my parking brake is bodged, goes right to the floor and car still drives, so I have to dig into it on the weekend if I get time. Figured i'd research it first so I know how to adjust it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the one to three notches that you should consider - this is, effectively, the slack allowable in the system and it is what has to be adjusted out to give you a working parking brake according to your later comment.

Comment: Tried adjusting the slack and even when the adjustment nut is fully tightened, still no brake, so something more significant. Kinda stopped looking at this after I noticed that my rear differential is leaking oil ... looks like a horrible job to do involving removing all sorts of things ... hmmm